# Famous (aka Famo.us) with Backbone router?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing, famo.us

Anyone know how to use Famou.us with a router, i.e. Backbone? They have a slick looking Twitter clone, but it doesn't update the URL in web browser. Looking for a decent router option for Famous. See the Twitter clone here: 
http://demo.famo.us/tweetus

Comment: because that's a single-screen with hidden elements, it's a physics engine with rendering ability. It's like using jqueryUI elements in one of the Backbone Views. If you can think of a specific issue, we can help more, but this is very generic question, plus would be great to see what you've already tried.

Comment: I read a blog post on using Meteor's Iron Router with Famo.us, it wasn't too overly complicated, just wondering if anyone has similar luck with Backbone. Meteor example: https://github.com/jperl/famous-meteor/tree/master/client

Answer (score 2):

Famo.us works really well with backbone. It pretty much replaces the View component, and the rest of backbone still functions.

Actually, it also makes the meat of marionette irrelevant too. (although i love the module and event stuff in it)

This document I found explains how they integrate:

https://gist.github.com/AdrianRossouw/d85ce9897c123c42b162